# Foreach and continue to create submenu columns

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, foreach, continue

I am using Opencart and Bootstrap 2.3.2 in order to try and create submenus with columns.
I have created an opencart module which is basically a copy of the category module. I am going to use this module to show the categories in my main navigation in dropdown menus. The problem is that if there are more than 5 categories then I want to create a new column within the dropdown menu.

The php I have so far is:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <ul class="box-category">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                <li>
                    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The outcome that I want is:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul class="box-category span6">
                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="box-category span6">
                <li><a href="#">Category 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have been looking into 'continue' for use within the foreach statement but some of the code (such as adding the span6 class to the ul) falls outside of the foreach statement. How can I modify my code in order to get the desired outcome?

Comment: Have you ever considered using a templating engine like [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php)?

Comment: @Brodie - Thanks for the link. To be honest it's a bit ver my head but I will look further into it.

Comment: I recommend this [Net Tuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-using-the-mustache-template-library/) to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

For this you will need to make use of the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php // The if statement should be true every fifth iteration ?>
    <?php if( $count % 5 == 0) { ?>
    <ul class="box-category span6">
    <?php } ?>
    <li>
        <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php if( $count % 5 == 0) { ?>
        <ul class="box-category">
    <?php } ?>
<?php 
    $count++;
} 
?>
```

This is fairly rough and can probably be cleaned up a bit, but should work (untested)

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Your example is not quite there yet but at least now I have something to work with. Thanks